# \graphicspath and \include

Tags: graphics, include

I am trying to define a central graphics path for my thesis, however, the chapters are included with the `\include` command and by using `\include` with `\graphicspath`, pdflatex complains about it can not find the pictures, is not that possible to use `\graphicspath` and `\include` together, for which I do not see a sound reasoning behind.

I use in the preamble

```
\graphicspath{{/home/utab/thesis/phd_text/figures_all//}}
```

and use

```
\include{ch9}
```

Then it can can not find the pictures on the above mentioned directories recursively.

Comment: @Umut: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).

Comment: @lockstep, Thx for the hints

Comment: It should work with an absolute path. Try to remove the doubled `/` at the end. That's the only thing I see here.

Comment: Does not that extra / make that to search the directories recursively?

Comment: @Umut what operating system are you using?

Comment: @Ulmut: I never heard about that. So far I know the underlying code this doesn't happen.

Comment: @Yiannis: linux

Comment: @Martin, I found that on the wiki pages and tried however your reply made it clear

Comment: @Umut: I just looking for it and also found it on the LaTeX wiki and some other places. I don't think it is handled in the LaTeX code of `graphics` or in the base LaTeX code, but it might be handled by the `(pdf)latex` executable itself. However, in my tests it doesn't work at all, neither for `\include`d files or in the main file.

Comment: @Umut Try running this code in a minimal with LuaLaTeX `\gdef\FindFile#1{%
\directlua{local function find_file(...)
    return kpse.find_file(...) or ""
end 
tex.sprint(find_file("#1"))}}
\FindFile{myimage.png}` and enter the path as is shown. Change filename to one of your images. See also http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=graphicspath

Comment: @Umut: Maybe the `//` is an extension of MikTeX. It would explain that it doesn't work with TeXLive under Linux, but that I find some posts online which tell that it works fine.

Comment: Try `\graphicspath{{figures\}}`

Answer (score 12):

The `\graphicspath` command does not influence the directories `\include` takes into consideration, because `\graphicspath` is from the `graphics` package, while `\include` is plain LaTeX.

Unfortunately, like stated on [Bits of document from other directories](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-docotherdir), there is no trivial way to build, e.g., an `\includepath` command. Nevertheless, the site mentioned above links two packages as a possible solution: `chapterfolder` and `import`, and especially the `\cfinput` command from chapterfolder might help. There is also another [blog post describing the use of `chapterfolder`](http://jevopi.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-write-very-long-documents-with.html).

Answer (score 12):

You can use relative path : give as a second argument to `\graphicspath` what would be the relative path seen from your chapter. In my own case, I have a thesis folder containing chapter folders and a Figures folder. I use :

```
\graphicspath{{Figures/}{../Figures/}}
```

Comment: With relative folders that should also work just using `\graphicspath{{Figures/}` as long as every `\includegraphics` the works in that directory. At least for me the secont part you use isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I could not get

```
\graphicspath{figures\}
```

to work as desired. I am using a makefile in my writing, though, so I specified an extra rule:

```
%.pdf: export TEXINPUTS=.:figures:
%.pdf: %.tex
latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode" -use-make $<
```