# Querying and modifying TEXINPUTS from inside a latex file?

Tags: texinputs

If I have images, or files that I `\input` or `\include`, I know I can use:

```
TEXINPUTS=/path/to/extra/dir pdflatex myfile.tex
```

... to allow Latex to find files not present in subdirectories in the current directory.

But, I'd rather not use TEXINPUTS as an environment variable on the command line - I'd prefer if there was something like a `\texinputs` macro that I could read or append to from inside Latex, so I could write my file as:

```
\edef\texinputs{\texinputs:/path/to/extra/dir}
\documentclass{...
```

... and then just run `pdflatex myfile.tex` on the command line (and have everything work as expected).

Is there a way to do this in Latex (that is, from inside a .tex file being processed by Latex)? (I'm aware that I could write a shell script, but then I have an additional file to think of; I'm also aware I could use something like `arara` (?) for this, but let's say I don't have the time at the moment to acquaint myself with a new tool).

Comment: Does this help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15960/graphicspath-and-include
Note that graphicspath exists for exactly this reason with images, the include statement is the "tricky" part.

Comment: +1 Oh I would **love** to have a feature like that. It would solve so many problems in my cross-site, cross-platform and dozen-of-participants projects.

Comment: thanks @zeroth - not really, as [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20079/2595) there says, `\graphicspath` is only for `{graphicx}`, and does not influence `\input`, which AFAIK is a `tex` primitive. Cheers!

Comment: `\graphicspath` is only  a wrapper around the general `\input@path`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241832/2388

Comment: Thanks, @UlrikeFischer - actually, it looks like that question, [Define path for packages in the LaTeX file (analog of \input@path or \graphicspath for \usepackage)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241828/define-path-for-packages-in-the-latex-file-analog-of-inputpath-or-graphicspa) does answer my question... but I'll need to test it eventually. cheers!

Comment: @sdaau the analogue for latex's `\input` (which isn't primitive) is `\input@path` in fact `\graphicspath` just saves a local copy of `\input@path` to be used by `\includegraphics`. If you set `\input@path` before loading `graphics` then teh same path will be used for tex files and images.

Comment: On the basis of the comments I'm marking this as a dupe: seems that is the best way to answer it.